# python hh:mm:ss to seconds on python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, time

I am trying to write a program that checks the avg speed of a road. This program will be where you input two times point1-point2.  Then the program works out the difference. This all works. The only thing I need is the difference output in HH:MM:SS and I need it in seconds or minutes. This will collect the time to convert from the difference. My code so far is:

```
from datetime import datetime
#start
print ("Welcome to This Speed Check!")

#varibles
distance=int(input("How far did you travel!(Miles)"))
time1=input("Whats was the time you went past the first point(H:M:S)?")
time2=input("What was the finishing time?")
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
diffrence = datetime.strptime(time2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(time1, FMT)
print(diffrence)
```

this all works and gives me what I want I need to convert diffrence to seconds

thanks Adam

Answer (score 1):

Since `diffrence` is of [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types) type, you should be using [`datetime.total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method as:

```
 print(diffrence.total_seconds())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by calling `seconds`:

```
print(diffrence.seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the time difference in seconds:

```
print(diffrence.total_seconds())
```

Example:

```
t1 = datetime.datetime(2005, 1, 1)
t2 = datetime.datetime(2006, 1, 1)
diff = t2 - t1
print(diff.total_seconds())
```

Output:

```
31536000.0
```

Looks alright:

```
print(365 * 24 * 60 * 60)

31536000
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds):

> Total seconds in the duration.